# Why the thread_info structure in linux(x86_64) is stuffed by 0?

Tags: linux, process, kernel

When I was debugging linux kernel process by the debugstub of vmware, I found a really strange situation.
I set a breakpoint in sys_execve and open the chrome, it did break but I found the thread_info structure is always stuffed by 0.

```
Breakpoint 1, SyS_execve (filename=139842677234776, argv=139842677234848, envp=139843191453696)
at /build/linux-lts-utopic-V0z0lI/linux-lts-utopic-3.16.0/fs/exec.c:1630
1630    in /build/linux-lts-utopic-V0z0lI/linux-lts-utopic-3.16.0/fs/exec.c
(gdb) set $hehe = (struct thread_info *)(((long)$rsp & 0xffffffffffffe000))
(gdb) print *$hehe
$21 = {
  task = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
  exec_domain = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
  flags = 0,
  status = 0,
  cpu = 0,
  saved_preempt_count = 0,
  addr_limit = {
    seg = 0
  },
  restart_block = {
fn = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
{
  futex = {
    uaddr = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
    val = 0,
    flags = 0,
    bitset = 0,
    time = 0,
    uaddr2 = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>
  },
  nanosleep = {
    clockid = 0,
    rmtp = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
    compat_rmtp = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
    expires = 0
  },
  poll = {
    ufds = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
    nfds = 0,
    has_timeout = 0,
    tv_sec = 0,
    tv_nsec = 0
  }
}
  },
  sysenter_return = 0x0 <irq_stack_union>,
  sig_on_uaccess_error = 0,
  uaccess_err = 0
}
```

And then I tried the same operations in 32 bit ubuntu 14.04, everything worked well.

```
(gdb) set $hehe = (struct thread_info *)((long)$esp & 0xffffe000)
(gdb) print *$hehe
$1 = {task = 0xc1980a40 <init_task>, exec_domain = 0xc198ef80 <default_exec_domain>, flags = 0, status = 0, cpu = 0, saved_preempt_count = -2147483648,
  addr_limit = {seg = 4294967295}, restart_block = {fn = 0xc106d520 <do_no_restart_syscall>, {futex = {uaddr = 0x0, val = 0, flags = 0, bitset = 0, time = 0,
    uaddr2 = 0x0}, nanosleep = {clockid = 0, rmtp = 0x0, expires = 0}, poll = {ufds = 0x0, nfds = 0, has_timeout = 0, tv_sec = 0, tv_nsec = 0}}},
  sysenter_return = 0x0, sig_on_uaccess_error = 0, uaccess_err = 0}
```

I wonder what made these happened.
The default PAGE_SIZE is not 4KB? Or the thread stacks are not THREAD_SIZE (2*PAGE_SIZE) big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacks are 16KB for quite some time now. I don't see why would you play the guessing game nor why are you looking for thread_info. If you are trying to get the task_struct you can get to it through %gs.

Comment: I tried to write a exploitation for a kernel vulnerability. So I need to find the thread_info through the address of stack I leaked. It's useful if I change the size to 16KB, thank you very much that solved my problem perfectly.